# xhtmlrenderer xhtml to pdf font problem, even not working with font-family: Verdana;

Tags: javascript, java, css, spring-mvc, flying-saucer

I am using flyingSaucer to generate PDF from HTML and CSS.

The rest code works very fine, other than font stuff. Below is the code I am using.

```
public void convertHtmlToPdf(String html, String css, OutputStream out) {
    try {
        html = correctHtml(html);
        html = getFormedHTMLWithCSS(html, css);

        HtmlCleaner cleaner = new HtmlCleaner();
        TagNode rootTagNode = cleaner.clean(html);
        CleanerProperties cleanerProperties = cleaner.getProperties();
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new PrettyXmlSerializer(cleanerProperties);
        String cleanedHtml = xmlSerializer.getAsString(rootTagNode);


        File fontFile = new File("/omegaengineeringservices/Verdana.ttf");
        FontFactory.register(fontFile.getAbsolutePath());

        ITextRenderer r = new ITextRenderer();
        FontResolver resolver = r.getFontResolver();

        r.getFontResolver().addFont(fontFile.getAbsolutePath(), BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
        r.setDocumentFromString(cleanedHtml);

        r.layout();
        r.createPDF(out);
        r.finishPDF();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

I too have Have added same font in my CSS.

```
.manual-body-center{
        width:100%;
        font-family: Verdana;
    }
```

As a result, I am getting an error that,

```
ExceptionConverter: java.io.IOException: /omegaengineeringservices/Verdana.ttf not found as file or resource.
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.RandomAccessFileOrArray.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.TrueTypeFont.process(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.TrueTypeFont.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.BaseFont.getAllFontNames(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.FontFactoryImp.register(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.FontFactory.register(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.FontFactory.register(Unknown Source)
    at com.omegaengineering.services.pdf.impl.Converter.convertHtmlToPdf(Converter.java:40)
    at com.omegaengineeringmanualsaddon.controllers.ManualsControllers.convertFromHtml(ManualsControllers.java:148)
    at com.omegaengineeringmanualsaddon.controllers.ManualsControllers.convertHtmlToPdf(ManualsControllers.java:131)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem with given file path **/omegaengineeringservices/Verdana.ttf**

You need to give valid path there, for more details please refer **flyingsaucer user guide**. In section **How do I add custom or specific fonts?**, there is example with details.

http://flyingsaucerproject.github.io/flyingsaucer/r8/guide/users-guide-R8.html#xil_32

Comment: https://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-can-i-load-font-web-infresourcesfontsfoobarttf following this link, i resolved my issue. I hope this works for rest.